# BigDecimal автодобавление 0

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
String s = ".1";

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(s);

    System.out.println(bd);
```

Хочу получить на выходе  (.1) без скобок. 
Получаю  (0.1)

В идеале на входе приходят строковые дробные десятичные, в том числе без 0 перед точкой, и необходимо получить на выходе то же самое, т.е без убирания/добавления нулей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat();
fmt.setMinimumIntegerDigits(0);

DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = fmt.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
fmt.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

System.out.println(fmt.format(bd));
```